# Crystal Reports 2008 - How Do you Freeze The Header or Columns of a Table

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

Can anyone help me with my query.

How to freeze the header part of Crystal Reports 2008 in the crystal report viewing time.

(the header part should be always displayed while the user scrolls down on the report).

I can't find any option for this.

Thanks.

Domdew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to achieve that in Crystal alone. But there are ways around that limitation.

For example, you can export the data from Crystal to Excel and freeze panes in Excel.
Or you can export the data from Crystal to a web grid.

There are 3rd-party Crystal Reports utilities that can automate these options.